# nixos installation issue,'command not found: nix'

Tags: nix, nixos

I deleted /nix and started a fresh install of nix, however after installing nix install nix (MACBook Pro M1 arm64   BigSur) with  `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install)`  I run `$ nix` but I get the output `zsh: command not found: nix` , same for `nix-shell`also the /nix volume is not created,  I also tried the instruction at https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html still same issue

Answer (score 31):

1. Open `/etc/zshrc` and look for the following lines (probably at the end of the file):

   ```
    # Nix
    if [ -e '/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh' ]; then
       . '/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/etc/profile.d/nix-daemon.sh'
    fi
    # End Nix
   ```
2. Copy these lines and delete them from this file.
3. Open `~/.zshrc` and add the above copied lines to the end of this file
4. Reboot terminal and nix should work now.

Comment: I tried other solutions, and this is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me, but after I restarted my macbook everything turned back. And this time, I already put that code into .zshrc but still can't find nix cli.

Comment: It seems that upgrading macOS system will remove/reset the file `/etc/zshrc` that was updated by Nix during installation.